# Extracting links using regex via php

Tags: php, regex

need a little help with the regexp i make... have some text where links are encoded like

`[NameLink ->link]` or `[NameLink->link]`

The link can be without http:// or www.
Tried to get it using this pattern

`/\[.{1,}\-\>.{1,}\]/`

but if there are 2 such encoded links in a row then it doesn't separate them and takes also the content between two links. Can someone tell me what's the problem? Thank you

Comment: Can you give an example of your input data, and then an example of what you would want out of that data?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use `+?` instead of `{1,}`. Also, have a read on [greedy vs. nongreedy](http://www.regular-expressions.info/repeat.html).

You may want to strip spaces using `\s*` around your `.+?`, this allows for both `[NameLink -> link]` and `[NameLink   ->link]`.